# How to print in Console while using Cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have written a TCP Client program in Python and want to make a executable out of it using Cx_Freeze.

I have used the setup.py file given as below:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
if sys.argv[1] == 'bdist_msi':
    sys.argv += ['--initial-target-dir', 'C:\TCP CLIENT\\']

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"], 'init_script':'Console'}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup( name = "TCP Client",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("MBMD TCP CLIENT.py", base=base)])
```

I want to print on the console when the exe runs.

For that I have used:
raw_input() 
but it throws an error:

[image]

My aim is to have some prints on the console.

Please help me so that I can have prints on my console while the Program runs.

Comment: The `Win32GUI` base is for GUI applications without a console. If you use that, you can't print, and you can't use `raw_input()`. To do those things, use the `Console` base instead.